# Ways to export easyui treegrid to excel and PDF

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

Iam just started to work with jquery and asp.net. Iam integrating **jeasy-ui tree-grid** **with asp.net (iam not using mvc pattern)**, i am able to get the sample tree-grid. Now i need to **export the tree-grid data's to excel format and also PDF format**.

I had refer'ed the stack-overflow link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972547/export-datagrid-to-excel-using-jquery-easyui)

but i doesn't help me.Can anyone help me out of this?

Iam using the following sample json provided in tree-grid

```
[{
"id":1,
"name":"C",
"size":"",
"date":"02/19/2010",
"children":[{
    "id":2,
    "name":"Program Files",
    "size":"120 MB",
    "date":"03/20/2010",
    "children":[{
        "id":21,
        "name":"Java",
        "size":"",
        "date":"01/13/2010",
        "state":"closed",
        "children":[{
            "id":211,
            "name":"java.exe",
            "size":"142 KB",
            "date":"01/13/2010"
        },{
            "id":212,
            "name":"jawt.dll",
            "size":"5 KB",
            "date":"01/13/2010"
        }]
    },{
        "id":22,
        "name":"MySQL",
        "size":"",
        "date":"01/13/2010",
        "state":"closed",
        "children":[{
            "id":221,
            "name":"my.ini",
            "size":"10 KB",
            "date":"02/26/2009"
        },{
            "id":222,
            "name":"my-huge.ini",
            "size":"5 KB",
            "date":"02/26/2009"
        },{
            "id":223,
            "name":"my-large.ini",
            "size":"5 KB",
            "date":"02/26/2009"
        }]
    }]
},{
    "id":3,
    "name":"eclipse",
    "size":"",
    "date":"01/20/2010",
    "children":[{
        "id":31,
        "name":"eclipse.exe",
        "size":"56 KB",
        "date":"05/19/2009"
    },{
        "id":32,
        "name":"eclipse.ini",
        "size":"1 KB",
        "date":"04/20/2010"
    },{
        "id":33,
        "name":"notice.html",
        "size":"7 KB",
        "date":"03/17/2005"
    }]
}]
```

}]