# Which dashboard analytics will support Parse.com data source?

Tags: sql, mongodb, parse-platform, database-connection, analytics

I've developed an app that uses Parse.com as the back end. I now need a dashboard analytics software package (such as iDashboards) that will enable me to pull data from my Parse.com database classes and  present some of that data in a pretty dashboard fashion.

iDashboards looks to be the kind of tool i'm after, but it only supports certain data source inputs such as JDBC, ODBC, SQL, MySQL etc. Not being a database guru by any means, i'm not sure if Parse.com can be classed as any of the above, but from what i've read it doesn't come under any of these categories.

Can anybody recommend a way of either connecting Parse.com to iDashboard, or suggest another dashboard tool that will support Parse.com as a data source?

Comment: Why not use Parse's own analytics dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue you are facing is that data coming out of Parse.com is going to be in json format. Most dashboards are going to prefer csv files.

The best dashboard I am aware of is Tableau and there is a discussion about getting json into Tableau here: http://community.tableau.com/ideas/1276

If your preference is using iDashboards then you need to convert the json coming out of Parse into a csv format that iDashboards can consume. You can do that using RJSON as mentioned in the post above but you'll probably have an easier time of it with a simple php or python script that periodically connects to Parse and pulls out data updates for you and then pushes it to your dashboard of choice.

Converting json to csv in php is addressed here: [Converting JSON to CSV format using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667418/converting-json-to-csv-format-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is much more fundamental than "unsupported file format". In fact, JSON data coming out of Parse is stored in a so-called *denormalized* form, which means that a single JSON data file may contain the equivalent of *arbitrarily many tables in a relational database*. Stated differently, one JSON file may translated into potentially many CSV files, and there's no unique choice of how to perform that translation.

This is a so-called ETL problem, where *ETL* stands for *Extract-Transform-Load*. As such, you may be interested in open source ETL tools such as [Kettle](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/). Kettle is supported by Pentaho and includes functionality that can help you develop a workflow to turn JSON data into multiple CSV files that can then be imported into iDashboards (or similar). Aside from Kettle, [Talend](https://www.talend.com) is also widely used for this purpose and has the same ability.

Finally, note that Parse is powered by MongoDB, and exports JSON data that is easily stored and manipulated in MongoDB. As such, a natural fit for reporting on Parse data is *any reporting tool built for MongoDB*.

As of the time of this writing, there are two such options:

1. [JSON Studio](http://jsonstudio.com), which is a commercial solution that is built explicitly for MongoDB and has your stated capability to produce dashboards.
2. [SlamData](http://slamdata.com), which is an open source solution, also built for MongoDB, which allows native SQL on the database. The current version does not have reporting capabilities (just CSV export), but the 2.09 version due out in June has reporting dashboards baked in.

An advantage of using a MongoDB reporting tool is that you will not have to wrangle your data into relational form. If it's heavily nested, using arrays, and so forth, it can be quite painful to develop an ETL workflow and keep it in sync with how the data is changing. Instead, all you have to do is built a script to pipe the raw data from Parse into a MongoDB instance (perhaps hosted by [MongoLab](http://mongolab.com) or equivalent, if you don't want to host it yourself), and connect the MongoDB reporting tool on top.

You might also contact Parse and see if they have a recommended solution for this. It occurs to me they should probably bake some sort of analytical / reporting functionality into their APIs as this is such a common use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Axibase Time-Series Database](http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/) to ingest your data from parse.com and they have built in dashboards and widgets for visualization or you can just export data from ATSD to csv and use iDashboards.