# How to write the output of a json to a CSV?

Tags: php, arrays, json, csv, curl

UPDATE: I changed the code:

The first keyword is working the second one doesn't write to the csv. The multidimensional array is skipped and written as "Array". Doesn't matter. The updated code now looks like this:

```
 $josn_decoded = json_decode($output, true);
 $file_name = "searched_book.csv";
 $fp = fopen($file_name, 'w');


foreach($josn_decoded['results'] as $search_result){





   fputcsv($fp, $search_result);
   }

 fclose($fp);
```

How can I write more keywords as rows in the CSV?

UPDATE 2:

Here is the output (sorry I can't get it displayed in another way):

```
      Notice: Array to string conversion in /volume2/web/static/buzzsumo/index.php on line 78 
       array(25) { 
          ["published_date"]=> int(1424081166) 
          ["linkedin_shares"]=> int(43) 
          ["google_plus_shares"]=> int(0)
          ["meta_keywords"]=> string(27) "payments technology company"
          ["total_shares_with_pinterest"]=> int(48) 
          ["article_types"]=> array(1) {
                  [0]=> string(15) "general_article" } 
          ["twitter_shares"]=> int(5) 
          ["og_url"]=> string(131) "http://www.thepaypers.com//online-payments/pay-on-launches-open-payment-platform-for-white-label-payment-gateway-solutions/758641-3" 
          ["url"]=> string(131) "http://www.thepaypers.com//online-payments/pay-on-launches-open-payment-platform-for-white-label-payment-gateway-solutions/758641-3" 
          ["pinterest_shares"]=> int(0) 
          ["id"]=> string(9) "405519905" 
          ["total_shares"]=> int(48) 
          ["title"]=> string(79) "PAY.ON launches Open Payment Platform for white label payment gateway solutions" 
          ["thumbnail"]=> string(51) "http://www.thepaypers.com/images/linkedin-share.png" 
          ["subdomain"]=> string(18) "www.thepaypers.com" 
          ["num_words"]=> int(206) 
          ["domain_name"]=> string(14) "thepaypers.com" 
          ["total_facebook_shares"]=> int(0) 
          ["giveaway"]=> int(0) 
          ["infographic"]=> int(0) 
          ["general_article"]=> int(1) 
          ["guest_post"]=> int(0) 
          ["interview"]=> int(0) 
          ["video"]=> int(0) 
          ["display_title"]=> string(254) "PAY.ON launches Open Payment    Platform for white label payment gateway solutions" 
           }
```

The article_types can actually be deleted because at the bottom there is the same again. Also I would need the keyword ($search_result) in the first column.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSON to CSV format using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667418/converting-json-to-csv-format-using-php)

Comment: @Wobbles - I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Mind if I ask the reason for CSV? JSON is typically a little easier to work with cross platform and language.

Comment: That will depend on what structure you have in your JSON. JSON can contain data stored in a format that CSV can not replicate. Assuming each element under `results` is a simple array of `key => value`, your code as is should work (though notice your variable name is `josn_decoded`, not to be confused with `json_decoded`), but if there are deeper arrays nested in each result, converting this to CSV can be a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Havenard: I will add the output. There is one multidimensional array and I get an error but in the CSV it just writes: "Array" and then it continues. But it only writes one line. If I queue two keywords it writes the second one and skips the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $json_str = "{'aintlist':[4,3,2,1], 'astringlist':['str1','str2']}";

$out = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
foreach(json_decode($json, true)['data'] as $key => $value) {
  fputcsv($out, $value);
}
fclose($out);

    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to help the OP, please include explanation why your answer would work, so that future viewers will be able to understand your answer.

Comment: Thanks Rohan. Unfortunately I am getting an error here:
Undefined variable: json on line 65
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 65.

I will post the arrays so you see the output.

Comment: @Rohan: The first error is gone, the second is the foreach() error, I think I need to find out if it is a string or an int and then write it correctly. I tried everything it won't work though.

Comment: @Rohan: That's the output:

Answer (score 0):

As you can see one of the elements nested in each result is an array. If you try to write an array to CSV, it will be converted to the text "Array", because CSV don't support this situation. You have to treat this case before writing to CSV:

```
foreach ($josn_decoded['results'] as $search_result)
{
    $search_result['article_types'] = implode(', ', $search_result['article_types']);
    fputcsv($fp, $rearch_result);
}
```