# Converting comma-separated API response to CSV

Tags: php, api, csv

I am running an API, the response of this API is returning response in comma separated values.

I am returning response in `$result`.

Response:

```
lmd_id,status,title,description,code,categories,store,url,link,start_date,expiry_date,coupon_type 106864,new,"Gift Vouchers worth ₹2000 @ for just ₹999","Get it for just ₹999",,"Gift Items","ABC Company",http://example1.com,http://example2.com,"2016-04-07 00:00:00","2016-05-01 00:00:00",sale
```

Below are the headers in response:

```
lmd_id,status,title,description,code,categories,store,url,link,start_date,expiry_date,coupon_type
```

Code I have tried:

```
  function str_putcsv($result) {
        # Generate CSV data from array
        $fh = fopen('php://temp', 'rw'); # don't create a file, attempt
                                         # to use memory instead

        # write out the headers
        fputcsv($fh, array_keys(current($result)));

        # write out the data
        foreach ( $result as $row ) {
                fputcsv($fh, $row);
        }
        rewind($fh);
        $csv = stream_get_contents($fh);
        fclose($fh);

        return $csv;
}
```

With the code above I am not able to find where this code is generating CSV.

Another code:

```
    $fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w');
foreach($data as $line){
    $val = explode(",",$line);
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Above code is generating file on FTP but there is no data in it. It is generating blank CSV.

I want to convert this response into CSV file and put it on a FTP or in the same directory.

Comment: You should post what you have treid so far. People will be willing to help you improve/fix your code but this is not a coding service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSON to CSV format using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667418/converting-json-to-csv-format-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can just put everything in an array. And use `int fputcsv ( resource $handle , array $fields [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape_char = "\" ]]] )`

Example from php.net:

```
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('path/to/file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

read more about fgetcsv [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)